# mySQL SELECT then UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple mySQL query that extracts the latest records added to my sales database

The query is run every 5 minutes via a PHP script and then the data is posted to an external URL.

I need to be able to update the database to advise me which records were extracted during that particular run of the query.

Very new to mySQL and php so apologies in advance if I have been unclear but if anyone could help me out that would be great

Comment: What do you want to do actually? Could you be more specific?

Comment: `UPDATE` some column with a unique identifier of your run, where that column is empty, `SELECT` those records & post them. Make sure new records have that column empty. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: You should add a timestamp column with a default of the current time.  Then you can look at the table and look at the `CreatedAt` field to see when the record was inserted.

Comment: thanks guys - both of those suggestions should work. I will try both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add some kind of marker / flag - which will help you to mark records that have been already sent. lets say you have field named "checked" for this purpose.

pseudo code:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE checked!=1;
send the data...
UPDATE table SET checked=1 WHERE checked!=1
```

...the last line would be safer to use id's of records that you selected before like:

```
UPDATE table SET checked=1 WHERE id IN (1, 23, 455 ,332)
```

Comment: thanks webdev-dan. This makes sense and I will try this out. I assume I can use the mySQL as the id you refer to?

Comment: i'm not sure if i know what you are asking about... `id` in my example is just the name of the field i assumed you have got one as a unique key for identifying a record.

Comment: yes sorry. my mistake. I have a unique identifier in the database

Comment: this suggestion worked perfectly - many thanks @webdev-dan